# In procedural PHP project, Session is not working in live server

Tags: php, session

I have build a project with procedural PHP. This project is working perfectly in localhost, but when I uploaded in live server , session is not working .

I have called session in first line of any page. And I used `session_set_cookie_params` method. However, the session is not working .

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: try to see if sessions are enabled through `phpinfo()`

Comment: I checked it already, session is enabled

Comment: Use your F12 developer tools to see if the PHPSESSID cookie exists. 
Also double check that the servers hard drive is not full.